# Need to display restart is required dialogue box for custom plugin after installation in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

After any plugins are installed, Eclipse IDE asks to restart to reflect the changes. How to display that dialogue box and how to perform restart for my custom Eclipse plugin?

Comment: Read up on how to display an UI in eclipse and for restart you can use this API IPlatformUI.getWorkbench().restart()

Answer (score 0):

It is not simple to reuse the restart dialog so you would be better of writing your own that replicates the dialog.

Use

```java
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().restart();
```

to restart Eclipse.